# Fine-tuning model parameters in an systematic/optimised fashion

Tags: r, cross-validation, predictive-models

[Tuning parameters in R isn't a new topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25748/what-are-some-useful-guidelines-for-gbm-parameters).

I am embarking on some modelling of a large data set, with the goal to create a predictive model using **R**, selecting predictors analytically from an abundance: ~1000 observations of ~200 predictors. I will be looking at various methods, for example boosting.

All the methods I am looking at require fine-tuning of model parameters and I would like to optimise this process as far as possible - both in terms of effectiveness and computational cost.
In [this video on gradient boosting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXZKgIsZRm0) - which is all in Python - I saw
a function in the `scikit-learn` module in python called [`GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) that accepts a range for all model parameters and works through all of them to find the optimal set of parameters specific to your model, based on how you define *optimal*.

Is the established way of achieving this in R to use the [caret package](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/caret/docs/train) and `train` [methodology](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tuning-machine-learning-models-using-the-caret-r-package/)? This seems very comparable to the Python method linked above, but **are there different ways**? Literature references?

Comment: let tell us your model  and the assumptions. There are hopefully fast and reliable way of optimizing tuning parameter.